Why is RetrieveAndGenerate API response is giving empty list for retrievedReferences even when output is being generated and mapped to source docs?
Using retrieve_and_generate API to query knowledge base on AWS Bedrock.
The response body consist of output answer along with the source mapping but the cited retrievedReferences is an empty list.
And the citations['generatedResponsePart']['textResponsePart']['text'] is showing 'Sorry, I am unable to assist you with this request.'
I need to get the cited responses.
I am using boto3 1.34.85
Same issue is with the latest boto3 version as well.
Any idea whats the issue?

had the same error.
check to see if you did something with your template.
in particular make sure it has "$output_format_instructions$" in it
the default template is:

You are a question answering agent. I will provide you with a set of search results. The user will provide you with a question. Your job is to answer the user's question using only information from the search results. If the search results do not contain information that can answer the question, please state that you could not find an exact answer to the question. Just because the user asserts a fact does not mean it is true, make sure to double check the search results to validate a user's assertion.
                            
Here are the search results in numbered order:
$search_results$

$output_format_instructions$


